# Numpy and Skimage Multiprocessing

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, scikit-image

Im currently working on some image processing stuff and wanted to make it a bit faster through multiprocessing library, but I can't grasp how exactly to do it. `

```
def slice_pre(slice_nr):

    data_normalized = normalize(data[slice_nr,:,:])
    data_oryg = data_normalized.copy()
    data_hist = exposure.equalize_adapthist(data_normalized, clip_limit = 0.1)

    data_median = filters.median(data_hist, selem = disk(3))
    data_median = exposure.adjust_gamma(data_median, gamma = 10)

    thresholds = filters.threshold_multiotsu(data_median)
    regions = np.digitize(data_normalized, bins=thresholds)

    data_normalized[regions != 2] = 0

    data_pre = exposure.equalize_hist(data_normalized)

    thresholds = filters.threshold_multiotsu(data_pre)

    regions = np.digitize(data_pre, bins=thresholds)
    data_mask = label2rgb(regions)
    data_mask = rgb2gray(data_mask)
    data_mask[data_mask != np.max(data_mask)] = 0
    data_mask[data_mask == np.max(data_mask)] = 1
    data_mask = closing(data_mask, selem = disk(3)).astype(int)
    data_mask = remove_small_holes(data_mask, area_threshold=300)

    data_eq = exposure.equalize_adapthist(data_oryg, clip_limit = 0.15)
    data_preprocessed = data_eq*data_mask
    data_preprocessed = opening(data_preprocessed, selem = disk(3))

    data_masks[slice_nr,:,:] = data_mask
    data_preprocessed_vol[slice_nr,:,:] = data_preprocessed

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(num_cores)                         
    pool.map(slice_pre, slice_nr_list)`
```

This is code I currently have and I would appreciate help to make it work.

Edit: Forgot to post slice_nr_list definition so here it is

```py
slice_nr_list = [slice_nr for slice_nr in range(data.shape[0])]
```

Comment: What's the exact problem you are having? In what way does the code _not_ do what you want?

Comment: My bad should have specified this right away. So, when i run it is seems to not put those processed slices in those three dimensional arrays. Those arrays are made with np.zeroes, my assumption is that this function doesn't start, because when printed it show only black images.

Comment: Tried printing some simple string from inside this function and it doesn't print so my assumtion was correct.

Comment: I don't know what this code do but every multiprocess uses own memory so they don't use the shared data. You have to send data to every process - `def slice_pre(data, slice_nr):`.  And you have to send it back to main process - `return  result`. And get it as `all_result =  pool.map(slice_pre, slice_nr_list)` but it needs list of tuples `[(data, number1), (data, number2),....]` instead of `slice_nr_list`

Comment: BTW: instead of `slice_nr_list = [slice_nr for slice_nr in range(data.shape[0])]` you can do `slice_nr_list = list(range(data.shape[0]))` or maybe it will works even without `list` - `slice_nr_list = range(data.shape[0])`

Answer (score 0):

Your function should handle a single unit of work, in this case an image slice, and return the modified unit. Your code is a tiny bit trickier since you are getting an image and mask out, but it's easy enough to unpack at the end.

Modify you function to take in an array, process it and return the modified array and mask. You can then iterate over the image directly:

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool

def slice_pre(image_slice):
    # Data processing here....
    # Just perform some dummy operations as an example
    data_preprocessed = image_slice * 1.5
    data_mask = image_slice > 0

    return data_preprocessed, data_mask

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_cores = 2
    input_images = np.ones((20, 100, 100), dtype = float)

    with Pool(processes = num_cores) as pool:
        data_processed = pool.map(func = slice_pre, iterable = input_images)

    # data_processed is a list of tuples
    # Unpack the list to separate tuples, and convert back to numpy arrays
    images_processed, masks = zip(*data_processed)
    images_processed = np.asarray(images_processed)
    masks = np.asarray(masks)

    print(images_processed.shape)
    print(images_processed.dtype)
    print(masks.shape)
    print(masks.dtype)
```

Output:

```
(20, 100, 100)
float64
(20, 100, 100)
bool
```

Note that `Pool.map` results are ordered, so the slices will be returned as they are input.